# How to fetch Total no of Comments and LIkes of Youtube Video through Youtube API?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am trying to fetch total no of comments and likes of youtube video. But I am unable to fetch it.

I am using youtube API : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=[api_key]&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet&videoId=[youtube_id]&maxResults=50

How can i do it?

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=YOUTUBE_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY
>        &part=statistics

Output:

```
"statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3057",
    "likeCount": "25",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "17",
    "commentCount": "12"
}
```

Check this for more information

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#Sample_Partial_Requests